# Is there anyway using PanResponder handle multi-touch event

Tags: react-native

I try to use two PanResponder to handle multi-touch event. One PanResponder in charge of upper half screen, and one lower. The two PanResponders work fine as long as there only one finger touch the screen. But when I put two finger on the screen, only one PanResponder works. So I only know coordinate( movement) of one finger and have no idea what status of the other finger is.

Comment: Did you find a solution @tennist?

Comment: Unfortunately, no......

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm I have this behavior and was unable to get an array of 2 touches with PanResponder.

It seems other people reported the problem in the past: https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/panresponderonpanrespondermove-not-responding-for-pinch